# Extend Angular Component method with injected services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to handle Angular component's destruction event in my external module providing decorating function. Unfortunately I am unable to override `ngOnDestroy()` method when it contains references to injected services... How can I go over it or achieve the same effect other way?

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/YtczREB91A3t6rJ1uKks (error in `ngOnDestroy()` shouldn't be thrown)

If anyone would be interested in this, here is the working version thanks to @estus'es proposition with `Symbol()`: https://plnkr.co/edit/nnxLswhPUGZR3ycBWojg

Comment: I think you should first implement ngOnit using your service then, use ngOndestroy to destroy it

Comment: `ngOnInit` has nothing to do about it. As you can see in the demo router is properly injected inside constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnDestroy` method is overridden with listed decorator. The actual problem with it is that wrong context is applied to `originalFunction` in

```
originalFunction.apply(target, arguments);
```

In case of method/property decorators [`target` argument is class prototype for instance properties/methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators):

```
export const ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL = Symbol();

export function Decorator() {
  return (target: any, propertyName: string) => {
    target[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL] = target.ngOnDestroy;
    target.ngOnDestroy = function() {
      this[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL]();
      console.log('Component destroy event successfully handled!');
    }
  }
}
```

If `ngOnDestroy` method doesn't necessarily exist but the decorator should be applied any way, it can be class decorator instead, where `target` is class constructor:

```
export function Decorator() {
  return (target: any, propertyName: string) => {
    target.prototype[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL] = target.prototype.ngOnDestroy || () => {};
    target.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {
      this[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL]();
      console.log('Component destroy event successfully handled!');
    }
  }
}

...
Decorator()
Component(...)
class ...
```

Comment: Yes, it's extended by overriding... The question is: how should I invoke the `originalFunction` to avoid problems with injected services? Well, it is a property decorator for storing variables in localStorage etc (ngx-store)

Comment: Wrap it with try...catch?.. At this point this looks more like XY problem to me. It's not clear why the errors are tolerated in original ngOnDestroy (they obviously shouldn't).

Comment: Try-catch doesn't make sense because I don't want to change default behavior and method overridden this way simply stops working...

Comment: I want to keep original `ngOnDestroy()` method's functionality and do some stuff related to the library providing decorator (in the demo is just console.log saying that it's done). Can you think of any other way to achieve it except using additional class decorator? (what doesn't make sense in this project) It looks weird to me since every other property and method is accessible, excluding the injected ones...

Comment: Estus, please take a look at `ngx-store`'s README: https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store#angular-storage There is exactly described how the decorators are used. Hope it clears the Decorator's purpose.

Comment: I surely know what are use cases for decorators. I see what's the problem here. `target` is not class instance, thus wrong context is applied to originalFunction. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Just wanted to show why it can't be a class decorator. Yes, it seems so, I've also tried something like `(() => originalFunction())();` but result was nearly the same..

Comment: It should be instead `originalFunction.apply(this, arguments)`. A more clear, debuggable and testable way is to assign original method to the object, so it could be called with right context like `this._ngOnDestroy()`. It can be class decorator and it likely should. The thing I meant is that the decorator was appiled to `name` property, yet it affected not `name` but `ngOnDestroy`, which looked out of place.

Comment: I just need to remove cache for decorated variable on component's destruction. And since TypeScript doesn't have destructors I am forced to do it some other way... Additional class decorator would be an API-killer. Maybe it's possible to watch some Angular lifecycle events so I'd know when the component is destructed without using additional decorators?

Comment: This makes sense. Yes, I would say property decorator is the right place to do that. I would suggest to use a symbol instead of `_ngOnDestroy` name then, since it may be patched multiple times. I'm not sure if it's possible to hack into compiler to do that.

Comment: It should be patched several times for every decorator included in the class. Okay, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I updated the answer with relevant details. Just notice that ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL should be defined for each decorator that affects ngOnDestroy if there are several of them, so they wouldn't overwrite each other.

Comment: I'm not yet sure how it works, but it does... That's amazing, you've just saved open-source project! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Again, this could be fixed with just `originalFunction.apply(this, arguments)`, but exposing unpatched method on original object usually has more benefits that keeping originalFunction private.