# target in javascript decorator is missing its properties

Tags: javascript, decorator, aurelia

I'm trying to build a simple pub-sub decorator for an Aurelia project, and I've hit a roadbump.

When I come to make the callback from the subscription, the target in the decorator has no properties, only methods. I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

The decorator

```
class AuxPubSub {
constructor() {
    this.subs = [];
}

subscribe = func => {
    return (target, name, descriptor) => {
        console.log(`subscribing ${func}`);

        console.log("Subscribe target: ", target);

        this.subs[func] = this.subs[func] || [];
        this.subs[func].push({obj: target, fn: descriptor.value});

        return descriptor;
    };
}

publish = func => {
    return (target, name, descriptor) => {
        console.log(`publishing ${func}`);

        console.log("Publish target: ", target);

        const origFunction = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = () => {
            console.log("Calling back.");

            origFunction.apply(target, arguments);

            for (let sub of this.subs[func]) {
                sub.fn.apply(sub.obj);
            }
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}
}
```

The publisher

```
export class FirebaseWrapper {
    isLoggedIn;

    @publish("firebase.isLoggedIn")
    setLoggedIn(state) {
        console.log("Setting state");
        this.isLoggedIn = state;
    }
}
```

The subscriber

```
export class App {
    showLogin;
    showRegistration;
    email;
    password;
    isLoggedIn;

    @subscribe("firebase.isLoggedIn")
    setLoggedIn() {
      console.log("Setting log in state.", this);
      this.isLoggedIn = this.firebase.getLoggedInState;
    }
}
```

The target of the publish decorator has one property (isLoggedIn) as expected.

The target of the subscribe decorator has no properties but all the correct methods

Comment: Why are your decorators part of a class and not just functions being exported from a module?

Comment: @AshleyGrant - it's because they share state. Is there a better way to do it? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I would say it's probably the wrong way to accomplish this. Ignoring that though, why aren't you just using the Aurelia Event Aggregator for this? It really seems like you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: One word: inexperience. I'm using EA now. Took all of a few minutes to get working. Thanks for your help @AshleyGrant

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `target` is class prototype, not instance (see also [this similar TypeScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980327/extend-angular-component-method-with-injected-services)).

This makes `origFunction` being called with wrong context. It likely should be:

```
const {subs} = this;
descriptor.value = function () {
    console.log("Calling back.");

    origFunction.apply(this, arguments);

    for (let sub of subs[func]) {
        sub.fn.apply(sub.obj);
    }
};
```

Also, `arguments` are not allowed inside arrow functions.